# trying to compile/ link tweak on iphone with theos and gcc

Tags: iphone, gcc, mobile

ive been trying to compile a mobile substrate tweak forever, but with no luck. so far, it compiles to the point where i get a .o file, but never to a .dylib. I keep getting the error:

ld: framework not found Foundation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

right after it says linking
i know the foundation/foundation.h is in the include folder

ive googled forever but have found no answer 
please help!
btw im on ios 4.1 ipod touch 2gmc and theos and perl were installed fine
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

projname_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit Foundation

add this below the projname_FILES